# Receive only one parameter in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

Let's suppose that we're calling a function that expects two parameters but it could work with only one because the second argument is optional and the function that we're using has a callback with more than one argument:

```
['1','2','3'].map(parseInt);
```

In this particular case, the output would be `NaN, NaN, 3` because map callback's has more than one parameter (`value`, `index` and the original `array`) and parseInt expects two arguments (`number` and `base`) but it could work with only one parameter. So, to fix this and get the expected output, we can use an explicit callback like the following code:

```
['1','2','3'].map((value) => parseInt(value));
```

Is there another way to do that without using an explicit callback? If not, how do functional languages do this?

Comment: Try `['1','2','3'].map(Number)`

Comment: Great. But my question was related to a mechanism to prevent that if we have to use an specific function. Let's suppose that we can not use `Number`.

Comment: I think what you did with the explicit callback is perfect. You use an arrow function to create a new function accepting just one parameter for your specific need. That is functional programming in essence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly... no, you must use a type of function referred to as an Adapter(basically something that changes the input of one thing to another, like RGB to HDMI) and the specific adapter you're using here is often referred to as the `unary` adapter(accepts 1 argument only). There are of course other *ary(unary, binary, ary) adapters that you can use, but with a functional language you basically can use an adapter to change the footprint of a function when needed with a closure:

```
function unary(fn){
  return function(a){
    return fn(a)
  }
}
['1','2','3'].map(unary(parseInt))
```

Now that's not to say this is the only way to approach this problem. You could also just pass it to Number:

```
['1','2','3'].map(Number)
```

Or if you want to be a little weird use the shorthand `parseint` call(`+`)

```
['1','2','3'].map(v => +v) // using an arrow function for brevity
```

But at that point you've written a verbose single use adapter only for `parseint`.

Comment: Arrow functions can be really useful sometimes, but does anyone else think this `let unary = fn => a => fn(a)` is easy to read and comprehend.  I sure don't.  Syntax shortcuts can be overused and create code that is not as simple to read or understand as it could be.  Brevity is not the main objective when writing code.

Comment: For those using the lodash library, there is a [`_.unary`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unary) method which creates a function accepting a single argument, and a [`_.ary`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#ary) method to do the same for any other number of arguments.

Comment: it's the "shorthand" for `function(fn){ return function(a){ return fn(a) }}` which is just as hard to read on a single line. To be fair when you write an adapter or closure returning function it just gets confusing no matter what format you use. I could use a better label than `a` though like `arg`

Comment: @jfriend00 it may be more familiar to people who use a lot of functional programming or are used to the format of typed functional deceleration like `map :: Functor f => f a ~> (a -> b) -> f b` which is common in functional languages these days as a shorthand for type declaration and has been around for much longer

Comment: more information on type signature notation:  https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#type-signature-notation |  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature | 
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures |  https://hackernoon.com/function-type-signatures-in-javascript-5c698c1e9801

Comment: Uhhh, the whole point here is that putting anything that offers that functionality on one line makes it hard to read.  Your unary function definition would be a ton more readable to the average Javascript programmer if you used more than one line.  And, the target audience here should be the average Javascript programmer, not someone schooled in another language.  I just think people go a bit nuts with brevity and forget that writing ***readable code*** is a major objective.

Comment: `edit: new lines don't work well in comments... /edit` So if I'm reading these comments right you would have preferred the arrow function be

    let unary = fn =>\r\n
      a =>\r\n
        fn(a)

Comment: I like this, but it may be worth to point out explicitly that the answer to the OP's question is "no": It's not possible to do this without creating a new function (in whatever way).

Comment: @FelixKling I'll change the order of the first few sentences to clarify that more then. Thought my second sentence already pointed that out

Comment: Actually, I like what you put in comments in your answer.  Much, much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`.map`, as you're using it in your program, appears in *infix* position. This is common for object-oriented style where methods are dynamically bound to the objects they're called upon. Writing a more functional program perhaps starts with `map` function that has a more functional interface.

```js
const map = (f, xs) =>
  xs .map (x => f (x))

console.log (map (Number, [ '1', '2', '3' ]))
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Above, we utilize the same `Array.prototype.map` behind the scenes, but we call `map` in the *prefix* position, which is a more common functional style.

Alternatively, we could write `map` from scratch, if you please

```js
const identity = x =>
  x
  
const None =
  Symbol ()

const map = (f = identity, [ x = None, ...xs ]) =>
  x === None
    ? []
    : [ f (x), ...map (f, xs) ]
    
console.log (map (Number, [ '1', '2', '3' ]))
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```